# Rails 4 validate uniqueness with hash scope deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3.2 I have this syntax:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :sport_name, :scope => :sports_org_id
```

This is now deprecated in rails 4 but i can't figure out the new syntax. I want to validate both presence and uniqueness for a data field.

Comment: New syntax is at edge documentation: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Answer (score 20, accepted):

how about this ?

```
validates :sport_name, uniqueness: {scope: :sports_org_id}, presence: true
```

See [The Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) for more info. Your syntax dates from rails 2 !

**EDIT**

You can now also use the `allow_blank` option instead of a presence validation, which makes for nicer error messages :

```
validates :sport_name, uniqueness: {scope: :sports_org_id, allow_blank: false}
```